# Adding double-sided arrows on line in diagram

Tags: uml, enterprise-architect

I want to do transition diagram between screens and I need both side arrows like this:[image]
Can anyone knows where I can find this option in Enterprise Architect?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What kind of diagram do you use and what kind of connector?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. On Association Right click -> Advanced -> Change Direction -> Bi-directional
2. Locate minimized Properties window -> Left click/Hoover -> Direction -> Bi-Directional
3. Right click on one of the minimized windows (e.g. Team Review, Pan & Zoom, Model Mail, Model View, External Browser etc.) -> Element Properties -> (same window as in 2 after Left click will appear) -> continue like in option 2.
4. Press Alt+1 -> (same window as in 2 after Left click will appear) -> continue like in option 2.

Note, options 2-4 use the solution of @ThomasKilian.

As far as I know all those solutions should work in 8.0. I've been using EA since 7.5 and actually not much have changed in this part of GUI.

Answer (score 3):

Usually you can create bi-directional connectors in EA by setting the property like shown in this picture:

[image]

Comment: where can I find this window? When I right-click on line and choose Association Properties there isn't any connector properties.

Comment: Which version do you use?

Comment: I use old version 8.0

Comment: IIRC the solution described by @Ister is the one to used for older releases (I only have saved version back to 9.3)